# Python: turning a tuple from return statement into a string

Tags: python, return, tuples

I've been working on HTTLCS and am having some difficulty finishing up the problem.

Solving a problem was not much of an issue, but I have trouble returning my result as a string rather than the tuple data type.

Here is my code:

```
def wordCount(paragraph):
    splited = paragraph.split()
    wordnum = len(splited)
    eWord = []
    for aWord in splited:
        if "e" in aWord:
            eWord.append(aWord)
    eWordnum = len(eWord)
    percent = round(eWordnum / wordnum * 100,2)
    return "Your text contains", wordnum, "words, of which" , eWordnum , "(" , percent , "%)" , "contains an 'e'." 



print(wordCount(p))
```

Python outputs `('Your text contains', 108, 'words, of which', 50, '(', 46.3, '%)', "contains an 'e'.")` which is a tuple, not a string.

I know I can just put print at the end of the function and call the function without print() statement, but how do I solve this with a return statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you're using commas in your return statement, which Python is interpreting as a tuple.  Try using `format()` instead:

```
def wordCount(paragraph):
    splited = paragraph.split()
    wordnum = len(splited)
    eWord = []
    for aWord in splited:
        if "e" in aWord:
            eWord.append(aWord)
    eWordnum = len(eWord)
    percent = round(eWordnum / wordnum * 100,2)
    return "Your text contains {0} words, of which {1} ({2}%) contains an 'e'".format(wordnum, eWordnum, percent)
```

---

```
>>> wordCount("doodle bugs")

"Your text contains 2 words, of which 1 (0.0%) contains an 'e'"
```

Comment: +1, best answer because instead of just giving the answer it explains the error

Answer (score 1):

```
return "Your text contains %s words, of which %s (%s%%) contains an 'e'." % (wordnum, eWordnum, percent)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return "Your text contains " + str(wordnum) + 
       " words, of which " + str(eWordnum) + 
       " (" + str(percent) +  "%)" + " contains an 'e'."
```

or

```
return "Your text contains %s words, of which %s (%s%%) contains an 'e'." 
        % (wordnum, eWordnum, percent)
```

In the first case, you do a *string concatenation* and you have to convert `wordnum`, `eWordnum` and other variables that are numeric ones, into `str` (by doing `str(variableName)`) to allow the concatenation (and for haven't runtime error)

In the second case, you do a *string replacement* that means that you give some kind of "placeholder" `%s` (that means string) and you replace them with tuple argument that follows the `%` symbol

If you return something separate by `,` you'll return a tuple (as you can see)

Answer (score 1):

```
return "Your text contains {0} words, of which {1} ({2}%) contains an 'e'.".format(wordnum,eWordnum,percent)
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop might work, though you would have to format the strings to add spaces to them.

```
for item in tuplename: print item,
```

Make sure to keep the comma after item, because that prints it on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```
def wordCount(paragraph):
    splited = paragraph.split()
    wordnum = len(splited)
    eWord = []
    for aWord in splited:
        if "e" in aWord:
            eWord.append(aWord)
    eWordnum = len(eWord)
    percent = round(eWordnum / wordnum * 100,2)
    dummy =  "Your text contains {0} words, of which {1} {2} contains an 'e'.".format(wordnum,eWordnum, percent) 
    return dummy


print(wordCount(p))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
return "Your text contains %(wordnum)s words, of which %(ewordnum)s (%(percent)s %%), contains an 'e'."%locals()
```

using `%(variable_name)s` as [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) is often easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
return "Your text contains " + wordnum + " words, of which " + eWordnum + " (" + percent + "%) " + " contains an 'e'."
```

replace the commas with "+", this should work.

Comment: No, it would not work since you missing conversion between integer and string into concatenation process